# How can I assure that the "<<" operator works for any generic type from within a templated ADT definition?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating a templated class that implements the functionality of a mathematical set. As it takes in any generic type, and as there is a display() function available, I want that to work with any type passed. How can I assure that this happens?

Comment: If someone intantiates your template with a type that does not have the required interface, it will fail to compile out of the box. What extras do you need exactly?

Comment: Suppose someone passes `struct not_working{}` to your templated class.  Do you want (A) your code to fail to compile even if nobody calls `display()`, (B) your code to fail to compile if someone calls `display()`, (C) your code to fail to compile and a nice error message is generated if someone calls `display()` telling the user what is missing, (D) something else (please specify), or (E) the templated class reads the programmers mind and writes an appropriate `<<` operator for `not_working` and silently works?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance and have the pleasure of enlightening me. I am just unsure how this works but I am assuming from @Quentin 's response that it is the responsibility of the type being instantiated with that it should have a << operator? If so, how is my set class able to use the << operator defined in another class? What kind of a mechanism is this?

Comment: Is (E) sarcasm or is that actually possible?

Comment: If you use the `stream << object` syntax, the language rules (namely operator overloading, two-phase lookup and argument-dependent-lookup) will ensure that the correct function is found and called without you doing anything else. You can also provide a catch-all version on the side that will try and do whatever it can with objects that don't overload `<<` themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
  public:
    explicit Wrapper(const T &value) : m_value(value) {}

    void display() const {
      std::cout << m_value;
    }

  private:
    T m_value;
};
```

If you try to instantiate `Wrapper` with a type that doesn't implement streaming out with `operator<<`, then your code won't compile.

So the simplest solution is to not worry about it.  Whenever the compiler tells you that the `operator<<` overload for the value type is missing, you'll have to add an appropriate overload.